# Find values of parameter $a$ so $\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\dfrac{n^{1-a}}{\sqrt{n^{a}+n^{2-a}}}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find for which values of $a$, the series converges:
$$\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\dfrac{n^{1-a}}{\sqrt{n^{a}+n^{2-a}}}$$

I have tried doing the ratio test but that didn't help. I am a bit lost. Can anyone give a hint?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: separately consider the cases $a<1$, $a=1$ and $a>1$, for which $n^a+n^{2-a}\sim n^{2-a}$, $n^a+n^{2-a}\sim2n$ and $n^a+n^{2-a}\sim n^a$ as $n\to\infty$. You should find the convergence condition is $a>\frac43$.

Comment: (That's assuming real $a$. For complex $a$, it's $\Re a>\frac43$.)

Comment: @J.G. Awesome thanks! But how did you get to it?

Comment: I started by trying to obtain the $n$th term's asymptotic behaviour, but I realized it would subdivide like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
S=\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\dfrac{n^{1-a}}{\sqrt{n^{a}+n^{2-a}}}&=\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\dfrac{1}{n^{a-1}n^{-a/2}\sqrt{n^{2a}+n^2}}\\
\\
&=\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\dfrac{1}{n^{\frac{a}2-1}\sqrt{n^{2a}+n^2}}\\
\end{align}$$

Case (1), $a=1$

$$S=\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}\to\infty$$

Case (2), $a<1$

$$S\sim\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\dfrac{1}{n^{a/2}}\to\infty$$

Case (3), $a>1$

$$S\sim\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\dfrac{1}{n^{\frac{3a}2-1}}$$
The series converges if

$$\frac{3a}2-1>1\Longrightarrow a>\frac{4}3$$